# Google Analytics Reporting API V4 for .NET having issue

Tags: c#, .net, api, google-analytics, reporting

When i run and try to run application i got below error on 
GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream); line.

"Error creating credential from JSON. Unrecognized credential type"

Below is my client_secret details.

```
{
  "installed": {
  "client_id": ".......",
  "project_id": ".......",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_secret": ".......",
  "redirect_uris": [ "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", "http://localhost" ]
  }
}
```

C# Code

```
// Create the DateRange object. Here we want data from last week.
            var dateRange = new DateRange
            {
                StartDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                EndDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            };
            // Create the Metrics and dimensions object.
            var metrics = new List<Metric> { new Metric { Expression = "ga:sessions", Alias = "Sessions" } };
            var dimensions = new List<Dimension> { new Dimension { Name = "ga:pageTitle" } };

            //Get required View Id from configuration
            var ViewId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ViewId"];

            // Create the Request object.
            var reportRequest = new ReportRequest
            {
                DateRanges = new List<DateRange> { dateRange },
                Metrics = metrics,
                Dimensions = dimensions,
                ViewId = ViewId
            };
            var getReportsRequest = new GetReportsRequest();
            getReportsRequest.ReportRequests = new List<ReportRequest> { reportRequest };
```

and

```
public static GetReportsResponse GetReport(GetReportsRequest getReportsRequest)
        {
            var analyticsService = GetAnalyticsReportingServiceInstance(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyFileName"]);
            return analyticsService.Reports.BatchGet(getReportsRequest).Execute();
        }
        private static AnalyticsReportingService GetAnalyticsReportingServiceInstance(string keyFileName)
        {
            string[] scopes = { AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly }; //Read-only access to Google Analytics
            GoogleCredential credential;
            //string Fpath = File.Exists(keyFileName)//System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("/" + keyFileName);
            string Path = @"C:\Users\umang.soni\source\repos\Google Analytics API Console\Google Analytics API Console\" + keyFileName;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                //I Got error on below line.
                credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
                    credential.CreateScoped(scopes);
            }
            // Create the  Analytics service.
            return new AnalyticsReportingService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Google Analytics API Console",
            });
        }
```

I googled a lot but not get any meaning full answer.

My application is console application.

Comment: does the Google sign in window appear when you start your application?

Comment: I have update my code. i am sorry i am not able to understand your question. please explain or check my code if you get idea.

Comment: has your application asked you to enter your google account details?

Comment: no it is not asked any account detail.

Comment: ok, first of all, it should be asking you for your account details, did you create a project on google?

Comment: Yes i have created project on google, then create Client ID , and add project name in consent details , then Enabled API for the same project and download JSON File and use that JSON File in my credentials. But i belive i am doing something wrong to create JSON. as it shows {"Error creating credential from JSON. Unrecognized credential type" message.

Comment: is the json file in your solution? if so, click on it, go to properties and make so it has `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy If Newer`

Comment: follow above step and make it copy if Newer. and run the project but same error occur.

Comment: strange that is hasn't asked you to enter your details. I would jump on the Google Forums and see what others have experienced as it should ask you for them to get authorization to your account and details.

Comment: double check that your application can see the json file at runtime.